# Best way to store editable config file php

Tags: php

*Introduction*

I've developed my own framework, actually all working pretty good. But now I've an important feature to implement: the configuration file. What I did now is very simple, I've this structure:

```
system
application
index.php
config.php
.htaccess
```

the `config.php` file in the root directory have the base configuration of the framework. Inside the `application` folder I've another config file related to my php application that runs on the framework.

*How the file work*

Actually the `config.php` file included in the `application` folder have this structure:

```
$config['LANGUAGE'] = defined('Config::Language') ? Config::LANGUAGE : 'english';
```

How you can see there is an array `$config` that check if a specific constant was defined, instead take the value passed. Note that `Config` is the class of `config.php` file located in my root directory.

*Problem*

Now this mechanism have a problem. I need to change some configuration over the air, so when my application is in used. Taking the previously configuration I take the default language from `config.php` file located in the root. But I can set the value through a `Settings` class that I've created for edit this value.

The `Settings` class make available two methods: `getItem` and `setItem`.

Actually I've used the session for allow the application to not lost the configuration setted previously calling:

```
Settings::setItem('LANGUAGE', 'italian');
```

this value is stored as:

```
public static function setItem($name, $value)
{
    $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
}
```

This way to work I guess is not the best option 'cause I need to develop a multitenant app with multiple databases, so I need to store sensitive credentials. And the $_SESSION maybe is not the correct place for store this.

I noticed that some framework use the same logic (twice config.php file) as Codeigniter, but I remember when I've used CI in the past, for store a credentials I did:

```
$this->config->set_item('some item');
```

and this was mantained. So, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: $_SESSION is per-user data storage, so it WOULD be the place to keep "live" configuration options.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for your comment. So you hint that $_SESSION is a secure place to store this data as I did?

Comment: can't say "secure", because that depends on how/where you're storing the data. but by itself, $_SESSION is tied to a particular user, and is not shared across multiple users. if two people are using your site, and you go `$_SESSION['foo'] = $username`, you'll have two session files with values `'fred'` and `'bob'`, and they won't get "crossed over" so taht Bob sees "Hi Fred" on the site by mistake. for that to happen, the session identifier would have to be leaked/stolen

Comment: Why not storing in a table and cache it?

Comment: that's another option. but test things first. see which one's fastest/easiests. How/where you store the data doesn't matter so much as how much it'll cost to USE that cached data. if it costs $0.01 and 100 milliseconds of CPU to pull data from the session, but costs $0.02 and 1 microsecond to pull from the DB, you'll have to decide which is "better".

Comment: @ka_lin you mean in the local storage?

Comment: @user3287550 no, I was thinking of memcache, look it up

Comment: @ka_lin this => http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php ? I didn't know it, I'll take a look, this working as a $_SESSION? Each user have their value?

Comment: You can share values or not, depends how you construct the cache key

Comment: @ka_lin very interesting I'll take a look at this, thanks !

Comment: This should be used with a sql table because you can't store in memory forever...as Mark said try several options with a big load of data to check which is faster and confortable

Comment: @ka_lin I know, but are only database credentials and multilanguage, other things are stored in the db

Comment: I would suggest a key value store like Redis.

Comment: If you are trying to store per-user data, then PHPs `$_SESSION` or a session-like mechanism is the way to go. Laravel for example uses it's own session mechanism and that mechanism does allow the use of memcache or files to back the storage. Since you're developing your own framework perhaps you should consider that solution.

Comment: @apokryfos I'll try to find some example for set and get items, actually thanks

Comment: You guys utterly confused OP http://stackoverflow.com/q/38996032/508666 ... Also no idea where caching comes in in all of this when there is no actual sign it is needed. @ka_lin